# How to add Microsoft.AnalysisService.AdomdClient.dll in Universal Windows Platform project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, ssas, windows-10, uwp

I have created a UWP Project in which I am trying to add reference to Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.dll for establishing connection with SSAS. But unfortunately I can’t able to add this assembly in UWP App. Could you please let me know how to add that assembly reference in my UWP Project and how to execute my MDXQuery in my UWP App in order to get corresponding CellSet.

```
Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdCommand adomdCommand = new Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdCommand(myMdxQuery, new Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnection());
adomdCommand.ExecuteCellSet();
```

If possible kindly provide us a simple sample holding these requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can’t do that. AdomdClient.dll is a classical .NET assembly, but UWP apps run on top of the Windows Runtime, so you cannot use AdomdClient.dll in your UWP app.

One option would be to create a classic .NET application (like a Console application, or do this in a Windows Service) and host the logic for AdomdClient.dll there and connect the UWP app via http (or some other protocol) to the logic.